# ios Tableview cell disappears when Selecting TextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that has custom cells in it. The section header on the cell has a selectable textview.

When you double tap and select the textview then tap away from it... the cell literally disappears. But when I scroll completely so that the cell is out of visibility and go back then scroll back... the cell comes back.

Very confused as to why this is happening. Does anyone have any idea what would cause this issue???

Issue is specific to the Table view header section, if I have selectable textview in the other cells and tap away the cell doesn't disappear.

Comment: Show your code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: I agree. Show code for the tableview

Answer (score 1):

I think you are designed the View for header as a table view cell. The disappearing issue is may be due to two reasons

1.Please check the tableview and cell views scope you declared.If it is weak please make it as strong.

2.I will give u a sample code you need to declare in view for header delegate
If you returned cell instead of uiview it may happen.Please verify that one also.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"QuizCreation2HeaderTableViewCell";

QuizCreation2HeaderTableViewCell* sectionHeaderCell = (QuizCreation2HeaderTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


UIView * headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sectionHeaderCell.frame];
[headerView addSubview:sectionHeaderCell];

return headerView;
```